# Flutter FlickVideoPlayer FlickManager play videos from server with SSL

Tags: android, flutter, ssl

I have backend server protected with SSL.
REST API works fine, iOS video player too, but I can't play videos on Android. Console returns these errors:

```
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(12438):   Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource$HttpDataSourceException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(12438):   Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(12438):   Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(12438):   Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

But I do not know why.
Network configuration file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">my-addr.eu</domain>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="@raw/my_ca"/>
        </trust-anchors>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Path to my certificate:
`raw/my_ca.pem` - if I move or delete it, console return another errors, so I guess my IDE see and can use this file.
Any idea how to fix it? Why I have problem on android, but on iOS everything is ok?